# Let $σ∈S_n$ be a $n$ cycle. Prove that an element $τ∈S_n$ only commutes with $σ$ if $τ$ is a power of $σ$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $σ∈S_n$ be a $n$ cycle. Prove that an element $τ∈S_n$ only commutes with $σ$ if $τ$ is a power of $σ$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose WLOG
$$
\sigma = (1 2 3 \dots n).
$$
Then
$$
(1 2 3 \dots n) = \tau (1 2 3 \dots n) \tau^{-1} = (\tau(1) \tau(2) \dots \tau(n)).
$$
So if $\tau(1) = i+1$ (for some $0 \le i < n$), then $\tau(2) = i+2$, etc  , $\tau(j) = j+i$ (Kasper correctly notes - thanks! - in a comment that once we get to $n$, we should fold over to $1$, essentially arguing modulo $n$), so $\tau = \sigma^{i}$.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't really get it. I think this is because I don't really understand my own question. Do I need to prove that: $τ=σ^i \implies στ=τσ$ ? What do you mean with $σ^τ$?

Comment: @90intuition, I have spelled out the conjugate. Yes, you have to prove $\sigma \tau = \tau \sigma$ if and only if $\tau = \sigma^{i}$ for some $i$.

Comment: Okay, so $⇐$ is trivial. And you prove ⇒ ? Aah I understand it, thanks ! You use the fact they commute to rewrite $σ$ right ?

Comment: And $τ(i)\overset{τ^{-1}}{↦} i\overset{σ}{↦}i+1\overset{τ}{↦}τ(i+1)$

Comment: @90intuition, right!

Comment: But what if $i = n-1$, then is $i+2 =n+1$ right ? Should I add modulo arithmetic notion ?

Comment: @Kasper, of course, yes, will edit and credit.

Comment: $( \Rightarrow )$ If $\tau\sigma=\sigma\tau$, then:
$$(a_1...a_k)=\sigma=\sigma\cdot \tau\cdot \tau^{-1}=\tau \cdot \sigma \cdot \tau^{-1}=(\tau(a_1)...\tau(a_k))$$
Notice that  $\exists i:0 \leq i < k$ such that:
$$(\tau(a_1)...\tau(a_k))=(a_1...a_k)=(a_{i+1}...a_k \, a_1...a_i) $$
So there exist $i:0 \leq i < k$ met $\tau(a_1)=a_{i+1}$. And $\tau(a_k)=a_i$. Consider $\sigma ^i$:
$$\sigma^i=(a_1 a_{i+1} ... a_k a_i...) $$ And notice that $\sigma^i$ and $\tau$ must be the same  $k$-cycle  \\

$(\Leftarrow )$ If $\tau=\sigma^i$, then $\tau\sigma=\sigma^{i}\sigma=\sigma\sigma^i=\sigma\tau$.

Comment: I'm doing the same exercise today at university, and this is how I would prove it, but I'm still not sure how you could show this verry rigoursly. I think this is fine tough.

Answer (score 11):

The conjugacy class of $\sigma$ is the set of all $n$-cycles, of which there are $(n-1)!$. Thus the index of the centralizer of $\sigma$ is $(n-1)!$, so the order of the centralizer is $n!/(n-1)!=n$. But there are $n$ powers of $\sigma$, so they alone commute with $\sigma$.